# Can't ping to 8.8.8.8 and google.com in beaglebone black

Tags: networking, embedded-linux, ping, beagleboneblack, lan

I can't ping to 8.8.8.8 or google.com

`root@arm:/home/debian# cat /etc/resolv.conf`

domain mshome.net

search mshome.net

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4

`root@arm:/home/debian# cat /etc/network/interfaces`

## interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

## Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

#/etc/network/interfaces

auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static

```
    address 192.168.7.2

    netmask 255.255.255.0

    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

[My configure for ethernet 3 and i shared internet for ethernet 3 from wifi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHtyd.png)

I shared internet for ethernet 3 from wifi and i can ssh to beaglebone black by IP 192.168.7.1 but i can't ping 8.8.8.8

My route :

root@arm:/home/debian# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.7.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0